# Adding test phone number in firebase phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to add test phone numbers for firebase phone auth, to skip otp screen or entering a predefined otp.

Answer (score 32):

The answer to this problem is you first need to remove you phone number from the Authentication>>Users tab, then firebase will allow your number in test list.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan Ahmed, best and simple answer

Answer (score 7):

first you need to check two points

1. Phone number is not present in user tab, if present then remove it from there(Build -> Authentication -> users)
2. Number is not blocked due to multiple attempt, if number is blocked then try it next day

after that you can add number by going to (Build -> Authentication -> Sign in methods -> Phone), you will find option for adding phone numbers for testing

Comment: Yes! Delete in user tab and phone add.

Comment: Is it possible to check that number is blocked or not in Firebase console or using code?

Comment: it can be checked while login, error should be shown if you make a toast of error while using firebase login in the phone

Answer (score 4):

You can test the firebase OTP phone auth on the authentication --> SignIn method as below.

[image]

Comment: @g,brahma how to solve error "error adding test phone number"

Comment: Check the phone number with digits. I got the same error when I entered more than 10 digits excluding the country code @JithishPN

Comment: If you have already used firebase phone number auth for your number, you will be listed as a User under Authentication -> Users. Delete your user data from that and try adding under Sign-in method. It works!

Comment: @Jithish P N : If the a user with the phone number exists in your project, you have to remove the user before adding the phone number as a test number

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue involves removing your phone number from the Authentication > Users tab. After that, Firebase will allow your number in the test list.

1. Go to the Firebase console and open your project.
2. Navigate to the "Authentication" section.
3. Click on the "Users" tab.
4. Search for your phone number in the list of users.
5. Once you find your number, select it and click on the "Delete" or "Remove" option.
6. Confirm the deletion when prompted.

After removing your phone number from the users list, Firebase will treat it as a new number and allow it in the test list for phone authentication. You can then proceed with testing your phone number in Firebase without any issues.

Remember to make sure you have the necessary dependencies and configurations set up correctly in your project for Firebase phone authentication to work smoothly.